# JavaM API for GT.M - SELECT support

Tags: select, java, mumps, m

I'm wondering if there's any possible way how to use or implement SELECT query into JavaM API for GT.M database system. I'm using version 0.1, since I haven't found any other version ( https://github.com/Gadreel/javam/blob/master/README.md ).

If there's no option yet, could you recommend me any other API for this DBMS, using Java? I know there's some gtm4j ( http://code.vistaehr.com/gtm4j ), but it takes advantage of springframework, which is not convenient for me.
I'm new with GT.M and I just want to test, how to connect to it using Java and use some basic queries. Thanks a lot for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database side of GT.M is a hierarchical key-value store, so features like SELECT (I'm guessing you want a full SQL SELECT) needs to be implemented by some framework (either an existing framework or one created by you).

From a quick look at the JavaM API, it seems it only offers/showcase a Java interface to the features offered by GT.M.  So I think you would have to implement the SQL SELECT feature yourself, in Java.

That said, it is possible that what you wanted to use a SQL SELECT for can be done easilly using the standard GT.M / JavaM API, so there would be no need to implement a full SQL SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you could use M to write a parser for your SELECT command syntax. And would certainly be easier to do with the GTMJI plug-in for full-duplex GT.M/Java communication that FIS have just released.